# Available techniques for having multiple clipboards in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, coding-efficiency

When programming, I need a way to have more than one clipboard (Vista).  I think two of them would do the trick.  For example Ctrl-C copies to clipboard #1 while Control-Shift-C would copy to clipboard #2.  Curious to know what software you use or maybe other methods altogether.

Comment: I'd love easy access to that in Visual Studio. It's the one thing I miss Most from using VIM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clipx.
http://bluemars.org/clipx/

It's the only way to fly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it at the OS level.

I will say in Visual Studio a neat trick is
Ctl-Shift-V

Will cycle through items in clipboard.

Got this from 
[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft%C2%AE-Visual-Studio%C2%AE-Tips-PRO-Developer/dp/0735626405/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626405)

Comment: That's pretty useful but very limited since only works with things copied from VS.